# Can we pull podman image with native docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, podman

The following is my setup:

- Docker repository in Artifactory (hosted on RHEL8)
- Jenkins slave (hosted on RHEL7)

The Docker repository has some images (built with docker) which I pull in my Jenkins slave using a docker plugin and everything works fine.
Now I have built an image with ***podman build*** and pushed it to the Docker repository. Now when I try to do a ***docker pull*** on my jenkins slave, I get an error stating image not found. But I am able to pull the image with ***podman pull***. Unfortunately podman pull is not working well in the Jenkins pipeline.

What I do:

**on a RHEL8 server:**

```
$ podman build -t artifactory/docker-repo/toothless:latest .
$ podman push artifactory/docker-repo/toothless:latest
```

**on a RHEL7 server:**

```
$ docker pull artifactory/docker-repo/toothless:latest
```

**result:**

```
Trying to pull repository artifactory/docker-repo/toothless ...
Pulling repository artifactory/docker-repo/toothless
Error: image docker-repo/toothless:latest not found
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
From registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9:9.1.0
LABEL maintainer:NightFury
COPY AppStream.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/AppStream.repo
COPY BaseOS.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/BaseOS.repo
RUN /usr/bin/yum install -y gcc git
```

I cannot build my image with docker on RHEL7 server because my image is of RHEL9. [RHEL9 image on RHEL7 host is not supported](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/rhel-container-compatibility)

I would like to know whether it is possible or not to do a *docker pull* of a *podman build image* from *docker repository*. Please let me know if I am missing anything in my process.

Comment: It doesn't look like podman pushed to the repository you think it did. There are features in podman to change registries, resulting in dependency confusion. If you aren't replacing the name of your registry with `artifactory` for the question, then note that's an invalid registry name and docker will reach out to Hub.

Comment: But I'm able to see the image in artifactory in the repository I'm pushing it to. Also "podman pull" of the pushed images works without issues. It is only the "docker pull" that doesn't find the image.

Comment: Are you pulling with the same user login? And please answer whether `artifactory` was changed for this question or if that's the exact string in your image name. We need to know if that's a valid registry name.